# Using npm and CakePHP 3 - file locations

Tags: node.js, cakephp, npm, cakephp-3.0

If you use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) to install a package in CakePHP the directory structure will be like this:

```
bin/
composer.json
composer.lock
config/
favicon.ico
.gitignore
.htaccess
index.php
logs/
node_modules/
.npmrc
package-lock.json
phpunit.xml.dist
plugins
README.md
src/
tests/
tmp/
vendor/
webroot/
```

So I've installed a package with npm like this, which has created `.npmrc`:

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro
```

This copies the files into `node_modules/`

But in Cake this isn't accessible because it would need to be inside `webroot/`

For example if you link to `node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css` you'll get a 404 because `node_modules/` isn't accessible to CakePHP where it is in the filesystem.

So other than manually moving the files - very tedious everytime you use npm:

```
mv node_modules webroot/node_modules
```

What strategy do people use in this sitation?

Cake version is 3.7 but I don't think that matters in this case.

Comment: I presume you're expected to copy the appropriate files to webroot

Comment: ... or tweak your CSS build script, if you have one, to do it for you.

Comment: Use https://webpack.js.org/ to build your assets. It will build and bundle your JS, SCSS and other frontend stuff and put it in a folder of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the [AssetCompress](https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress) plugin to handle these matters.
In the file `config/asset_compress.ini` you define your assets and their location and you control where (inside webroot) you want the compiled/compressed assets to be placed.

Follow the plugin installation instructions and add the following to the default/sample config/asset_compress.ini`:

```
...
[css]
paths[] = ROOT/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/*
cachePath = WEBROOT/cache_css
...
[awesome.css]
files[] = all.css
filters[] = CssMinFilter
...
```

and your template will use it like so:

```
<?= $this->AssetCompress->css('awesome.css') ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of this with some sample code? The filesystem we have is as shown in the question. So does AssetCompress copy them from `node_modules` to `webroot`?

Comment: To answer your last question: yes. I extended the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution that came to my mind was to create an action in your app controller that actually returns the script inside the node_module folder and create a route for it. Lets assume we have the following files:

```
/node-module/folder/sub_folder/another_sub_folder/style.css
/node-module/folder/sub_folder/another_sub_folder/script.js
```

First, add a new route to your config/routes.php. Something just like this:

```
$routes->connect('/node-module/*', ['controller' => 'App', 'action' => 'nodeModule']);
```

Now, create the action for your controller. This action should return a file rather than a page and we can make it using the response object of CakePHP.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;


class AppController extends Controller
  {
    public function nodeModule(...$path_pieces)
      {
        $file_path = ROOT . DS . "node_modules" . DS . implode(DS, $path_pieces);
        if(!file_exists($file_path))
          {
            $this->response = $this->response->withStatus(404);
            throw new NotFoundException("The requested file has not been found, holmes");
          }
        $this->response = $this->response->withFile($file_path);
        return $this->response; 
      }
}
```

And now you're all good to call your node_module files on the template

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node-module/folder/sub_folder/another_sub_folder/style.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/node-module/folder/sub_folder/another_sub_folder/style.css"></script>
```

You can even try to access the files directly on your browser like accessing yourapp.com/node-module/folder/sub_folder/another_sub_folder/style.css for example.